# Nested for loop is only iterating the last entries [r]

Tags: r

I am trying to extract each row of 32 dataframes from my list of dataframes. However, it only iterates the last value in both for loops. I am unsure of why this won't work but maybe I should initialize an empty list of dataframes instead of just an empty list?

```
a <- list()


for (z in 1:200){
  for (i in 1:32){
    a[z] = ListOfDataFrames[[i]][["X"]][[z,1]]
  }
}
```

This only produces a list of 200 values of ListOfDataFrames[[32]][["X"]] which is the last dataframe in the list.

Here is (str(ListOfDataFrames))

```
List of 32
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ X           :'data.frame':    200 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ pressure   : num [1:200] 635 640 760 890 900 900 910 920 1000 1000 ...
  .. ..$ pressure1  : num [1:200] 735 740 820 840 890 900 910 920 1000 1000 ...
  .. ..$ pressure2  : num [1:200] 645 670 760 890 900 900 910 920 1000 1000 ...
```

Comment: You should add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the structure showed, an option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <-  map(ListOfDataFrames, ~ pluck(.x, "X") %>%
              group_split(grp = row_number(), keep = FALSE)) %>% 
          transpose %>% 
          map(bind_rows)
```

---

With a `for` loop, it is better to initialize the `list` element predefined length

```
l1 <- nrow(ListOfDataFrames[[1]]$X)
a <- vector('list', l1)
for (z in seq_len(l1)){
  for (i in seq_along(ListOfDataFrames)){
    a[[z]] = rbind(a[[z]], ListOfDataFrames[[i]][["X"]][z,])
  }
}
```

-checking

```
all.equal(out, a, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
ListOfDataFrames <- list(list(X = structure(list(col1 = 1:6, col2 = 7:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), Y = 1:7), list(X = structure(list(col1 = 1:6, col2 = 7:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), Y = 1:7), list(X = structure(list(col1 = 1:6, col2 = 7:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), Y = 1:7), list(X = structure(list(col1 = 1:6, col2 = 7:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), Y = 1:7), list(X = structure(list(col1 = 1:6, col2 = 7:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), Y = 1:7))
```